# New line in express.js message

Tags: node.js, express, newline

Is it possible to make a new line in the message notification?

"\n" or "\r\n" just disappear but there's no new line set.
I also tried 
         `var endOfLine = require('os').EOL;` instead of \n. Doesn't work sadly.

```
res.render('settings.ejs', {
        user: req.user,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        message: 'Changed User(s):' + changearray + '\n(Notice: You can\'t affect Users with higher Settingrights.)'
        });
```

Probabbly a stupid/easy question but I don't get it working... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried html <br> tag??

Comment: Yes, just displays <br> in browser..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use html tags. The reason why they are not getting displayed is because I suppose you must be using `escaped` text. You need to use the `unescaped` syntax if you want to render the tags in your html string:

```
res.render('settings.ejs', {
        user: req.user,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        message: 'Changed User(s):' + changearray + '<br />(Notice: You can\'t affect Users with higher Settingrights.)'
        });
```

Here's how to display unescaped text in your view:

```
<%- message %>
```

Comment: Tried to unescape and to escape the text, even with unescape/escape function... As it's serversided, it just displays that <br> or escaped br tag.
Thanks tho.

Comment: Hmm. That should work though :( . Did you try as mentioned in this solution. I mean adding `<br />` on server side and `<%- message %>` in your view? What output did you get then?

Comment: Ahhh.. I was using <%= message %> instead of <%- message %>
Did check it thanks to you and now it is working. Thank you very much.

Comment: <%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
<%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template

Now reading the part on http://ejs.co/, I guess I got your point about unescape and escape now as well. 
Learned something new again, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set the header of your `res` to text/plain so that the server could know the type of content you are serving.
So - In your case - it could be something like this;

```js
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.render('settings.ejs', {
        user: req.user,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        message: `Changed User(s):` + changearray + `\n(Notice: You can\'t affect Users with higher Settingrights.)`
        });
```

This worked for me when I was trying to render some text content; i.e

```js
app.get('/students', (req, res) => {
  countStudents(dbFile)
    .then(() => {
      const content = `some text\n` + `some more text\n`
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).send(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    });
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      res.send(content);
});
```