# Rendering text files with escaped characters in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, text, escaping

I have a JSON object with a text file in one of its fields that I'm having Express render as "text/plain" when sending a response. However, whenever it renders, it ignores the '\n' line breaks in my text and just prints everything on one line without the '\n's. How do I get my line breaks in the outputted text?

My JSON object looks like this:

```
{
  filename: 'file.txt',
  body: 'hello\ngoogbye\nhello again\n'
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
config.textfiles.forEach(file => {
  router.get(`/${file.filename}`, redisCache.route(cacheRoute), (req, res, next) => {
    if (is.obj(file.body)) file.body = JSON.stringify(file.body)
    file.layout = 'blank'
    if (file.filename.endsWith('.txt')) res.header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    if (file.filename.endsWith('.xml')) res.header('Content-Type', 'application/xml')
    if (file.filename.endsWith('.json')) res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.render('blank', file)
  })
})
```

My handlebars template looks like this:

```
{{{body}}}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
hello goodbye hello again
```

What I am expecting and desirous of is for the output to look like this:

```
hello
goodbye
hello again
```

I have tried escaping with \n and \r\n but in both cases, it just converts them to a space. When I try \n, it renders \n as text instead of as a space.

Comment: d'oh i figured it out. why am i rendering a text file? if i just res.send instead of res.render without a template, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `<br/>` tags, `\n` is for `console.log` function, see this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456714/new-line-in-express-js-message), to display the `unscaped` html, keep the triple-stash `{{{...}}}`

Comment: unfortunately that did not work but instead returns with the <br>s, whether i do res.send with no template rendering or res.render with a template.

Comment: oh and not to be a pedant, but escape characters can be used in any kind of static text file, not just in a log file or the terminal.